# Scala FastParse Library Error

Tags: scala, fastparse

I am trying to learn the scala fast parse library. Towards this I have written the following code

```
import fastparse.noApi._
import fastparse.WhitespaceApi

object FastParsePOC {

   val White = WhitespaceApi.Wrapper{
      import fastparse.all._
      NoTrace(" ".rep)
   }

   def print(input : Parsed[String]): Unit = {
      input match {
         case Parsed.Success(value, index) => println(s"Success: $value $index")
         case f @ Parsed.Failure(error, line, col) => println(s"Error: $error $line $col ${f.extra.traced.trace}")
      }
   }

   def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
      import White._
      val parser = P("Foo" ~ "(" ~ AnyChar.rep(1).! ~ ")")
      val input1 = "Foo(Bar(10), Baz(20))"
      print(parser.parse(input1))
   }
}
```

But I get error

```
Error: ")" 21 Extra(Foo(Bar(10), Baz(20)), [traced - not evaluated]) parser:1:1 / (AnyChar | ")"):1:21 ...""
```

My expected output was "Bar(10), Baz(20)". it seems the parser above does not like the ending ")".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AnyChar.rep(1)` also includes `)` symbol at the end of the input string, as a result the end `)` at `~ ")")` isn't reached.
If `)` symbol weren't used in Bar and Baz, then this could be solved by excluding `)` from `AnyChar` like this:

```
val parser = P("Foo" ~ "(" ~ (!")" ~ AnyChar).rep(1).! ~ ")")
val input1 = "Foo(Bar(10*, Baz(20*)"
```

To make Bar and Baz work with `)` symbol you could define separate parsers for each of them (also excluding `)` symbol from `AnyChar`. The following solution is a bit more flexible as it allows more occurrences of Bar and Baz but I hope that you get the idea.

```
val bar = P("Bar" ~ "(" ~ (!")" ~ AnyChar).rep(1) ~ ")")
val baz = P("Baz" ~ "(" ~ (!")" ~ AnyChar).rep(1) ~ ")")
val parser = P("Foo" ~ "(" ~ (bar | baz).rep(sep = ",").! ~ ")")
val input1 = "Foo(Bar(10), Baz(20))"
print(parser.parse(input1))
```

Result:
`Success: Bar(10), Baz(20) 21`